# File doesn't exist! in wordpress function.php file while creating new post or page

Tags: errors, filesystem

i have been working on wordpress website, from past two days i am not able to add new posts/pages
while i click add new page or post, below image shows the error[image]

1. cant able to create new post
2. cant able to create new page

Comment: It sounds like one of your WP files has been deleted, but it's impossible for us to know how that happened. You'll need to get in touch with your hosting provider's support team.

Comment: in the same hosting platform other wordpress sites are running they are working fine, only while creating new post or page, getting this serror

Comment: i have compared with other wordpress files, files all are same, i dont see any changes in it

Comment: The **Fatal error:** at the end tells you which file couldn't be found: `{...}/wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php`. Are you sure that file exists? If it does, are the permissions wonky (eg the webserver process can't read it)? This is definitely something you should talk to your hosting support about.

Comment: all the files mentioned above are there in root folder, of the project